# how to format phone numbers in crm 2013 plugin using QueryExpression

Tags: vb.net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, query-expressions

i'm developing a plugin (asp page) who should get as parameter Phone Number and retrieve the matched client in `CRM 2013`.

the phone number is clean from punctuation marks and spaces
for example:

```
PhoneNum = Replace(PhoneNum, "-", "")
Dim query As New QueryExpression() With
         {
          .Distinct = False,
          .EntityName = "contact",
          .ColumnSet = New ColumnSet("contactid", "fullname")
         }
Dim queryCriteraFilter1 As New FilterExpression()
   queryCriteraFilter1.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.Or
   queryCriteraFilter1.AddCondition(New ConditionExpression("telephone1", ConditionOperator.Like, {PhoneNum}))
```

My question is how to format the field telephone1 same as PhoneNum in order to match the exact record.

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Phone number fields inside Dynamics CRM are stored as string.

If inside CRM they are stored like `0044-12345678` or `00441234 5678` you can't query them like "find phone numbers that are '004412345678' or contains `00441234`.

The solution is to save all the phone numbers stored inside CRM in the same format (for example using a plugin) so after you can query them using a `Like` or `Equal` condition inside your `QueryExpression`.